# Python Error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot an photoionization cross section. In that problem I have to calculate the dipole matrix elements by means of a double integral and plot the results for three different values of a variable called gamma. Here is my script

```
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import genlaguerre, gamma
from scipy.constants import alpha
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath

#Constants
epsilon = 13.1 # dielectric constant of the material
gamma_C = 0.5  # donor impurity linewidth 
nr = 3.2       # refractive index of semiconductor
flux = 0       # Phi in eqn 8 magnetic flux
R = 5.0        # radius of the quantum ring in nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)
rho = r / R
m_0 = 0.0067*0.511 # electron effective mass
h = 4.13e-15       # Planck constant in eV
hbar =  6.58e-16   # reduced Planck constant in eV

#Photon energy
hnu = np.linspace(0, 100) #in eV

#Function that calculates the integrand
def func(rho, theta):
    betai = gama**2/2
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    return R/np.pi*((gama * rho)**(betai + betaf) *
            np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) *
          (gama*rho)**2/2  * genlaguerre(1, betaf) *np.cos(theta) * cmath.exp(-1j*theta))

def cross_section(hnu, gama):
    #function that calculates the photoionisation cross section
    betai = np.sqrt( gama**4/4)
    betaf = np.sqrt(1+gama**4/2)
    Ei = gama**2*(1+betai)-gama**4/2
    Ef = gama**2*(3+betaf)-gama**4/2
    return (nr/epsilon * 4*np.pi/3 * alpha * hnu *
            (abs( np.sqrt(1/2**betai*gamma(betai + 1))*
            np.sqrt(gamma(2)/2**betaf*gamma(betaf + 2)) *
            nquad(func, [[0, np.infty], [0, np.pi]])[0])**2 * 
             hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2))

#Plot
plt.figure();plt.clf()

for gama in [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]:
    plt.plot(hnu, cross_section(hnu, gama))
plt.legend(['$\gamma = 1.0$', '$\gamma = 1.5$', '$\gamma = 2.0$'] )
plt.ylabel('Photoionization cross\n section $\sigma (10^{-14}cm^{2}$)')
plt.xlabel('Photon energy $h\\nu (meV)$ ')
```

But I got the following error:

```
    runfile('/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python/crosssection.py', wdir='/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python')
Reloaded modules: __mp_main__
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python/crosssection.py", line 53, in <module>
    plt.plot(hnu, cross_section(hnu, gama))

  File "/home/daniel/Arquivos_Python/crosssection.py", line 47, in cross_section
    hbar * gamma_C/(Ef - Ei - hnu)**2 + ( hbar * gamma_C)**2))

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 805, in nquad
    return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts, full_output).integrate(*args)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 860, in integrate
    **opt)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 448, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 860, in integrate
    **opt)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 341, in quad
    points)

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 450, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

I tried to debug the code in vsCode and it says that error is in the function cross section, but I still can't figure out what might be.

Comment: looks like `func` is supposed to be returning scalars.  Can you add a print function before the return to verify that it is indeed returning scalars?

Comment: I did what you asked and it returned an error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Comment: What exactly did you do?  I was merely suggesting that you add a line before the return of `func`, such as `to_return = R/np.pi*((gama * rho)**(betai + betaf) *
            np.exp(-1/2*(gama * rho)**2) *
          (gama*rho)**2/2  * genlaguerre(1, betaf) *np.cos(theta) * cmath.exp(-1j*theta))` followed by `print(to_return)` (or `print(to_return.shape)`) and followed by `return to_return`

Comment: And  I did exactly that

Comment: hm... that's really weird.  I have no idea what could be causing that.  You can try increasing the recursion limit with `import sys` and `sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`, but I'm not sure where the recursion is coming from.  Did it print some outputs before it errored?